# The RenderTransformOrigin does not work.UWP

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a problem that I don't understand how to solve it. I have a UWP application. In the XAML there is a Grid that has RenderTransformOrigin. But what value I would give it doesn't matter when I change the width of the grid the width is calculated from the center.

This is the XAML

```
<Page
x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid Background="White">

    <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="image" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Border x:Name="LeftScale" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ManipulationDelta="LeftScale_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY" />

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And the C#

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public Point Origin { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        image.Width = 500;
        image.Height = 500;
    }

    private void LeftScale_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Origin = new Point(1, 0.5);
        image.RenderTransformOrigin = Origin;
        image.Width -= e.Delta.Translation.X;
    }
}
```

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RenderTransformOrigin` is suitable for transformation. This transformation needs to be completed by the `CompositeTransform` you define. It cannot be changed by changing the `Width` property.

You can rewrite the code and try this:

**Page.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="image" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="imageCompositeTransform"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
    <Slider Maximum="500" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Width="500" 
            Margin="0,30,0,0" 
            ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```cs
public Point Origin { get; set; }
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    image.Width = 500;
    image.Height = 500;
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Origin = new Point(1, 0.5);
    image.RenderTransformOrigin = Origin;
    var proportion = e.NewValue / image.Width;
    imageCompositeTransform.ScaleX = 1 - proportion;
}
```

Transform the width of the control through `ScaleX` (not `Width`) so that `RenderTransformOrigin` can take effect.

---

**Update**

If you wish to do the width transformation of the Grid through your original code, here is the method:

```cs
private double moveX = 0;

private void LeftScale_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    moveX -= e.Delta.Translation.X;
    var proportion = moveX / image.Width;
    imageCompositeTransform.ScaleX = 1 - proportion;
}
```

However, because your `Rectangle` is inside the `Grid`, the width of the `Rectangle` will also change when the `Grid` width is transformed. If you want to keep the size of the `Rectangle` unchanged, it is recommended to move it out.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Fro the answer it helped me a lot. But the problem is that I need to do it with a mouse position and not with a slider.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code works great. That is the thing I wanted.